# How do I query my Wordpress posts on another HTML page using the Wordpress Restful API?

Tags: api, rest-api

I have a fully functional Wordpress site and I want the to create a new separate website that displays the posts from the wordpress site using the Wordpress Rest API.
I understand that typing http://my-website/wp-json/wp/v2/posts into a browser shows me this information but I want to code it into the new separate site. I don't even know where to start! Does  anyone know how to help?

Comment: This is like saying " I heard about that PHP thing, and I want to use it, where should I start? :( You start by having a concrete usage case which you detail in your question, and then maybe people will be able to advice you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use cURL to do server to server connections. There are plenty of examples online but here is a good starting point so you can at least know what functions to look into.

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: Please provide a CURL example then on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like the following and call it like `my_prefix_fetch_data( 'posts?per_page=3' )` or `my_prefix_fetch_data( 'categories' )`.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_prefix_fetch_data' ) ) {
    function my_prefix_fetch_data( $query ) {
        $response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( 'http://my-website/wp-json/wp/v2/' . $query ) );

        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            return array();
        }

        $output = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $output = json_decode( $output );

        if ( empty( $output ) ) {
            return array();
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```